# JavaScript - Join two JSON strings (nested array)

Tags: javascript, json, concatenation

I have two JSON strings that are constructed dynamically.
The first one is created from an XML Document:

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml_string, "text/xml");
    } else// Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xml_string);
    }
var json_str = xml2json(xmlDoc,"")
```

The other one created on the spot from user input.

Both have the same structure. The first one is:

```
{"Movies": { "Movie": [{"Title":"Movie1","Year":"2013"}]}};
```

and the second one is:

```
{"Movies": { "Movie": [{"Title":"Movie2","Year":"2014"}]}};
```

How can I concatenate these two so the result is two 'Movie' inside a "Movies": The result should be:

```
{"Movies": { "Movie": [{"Title":"Movie1","Year":"2013"},{"Title":"Movie2","Year":"2014"}]}};
```

I know that one method is to push *{"Title":"Movie2","Year":"2014"}* into *["Movies"]["Movie"]* ... but is there any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384845/merge-two-json-objects-in-to-one-object

Comment: You could use Underscorejs's pluck function (http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to pluck out all title's.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge two json objects with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478260/merge-two-json-objects-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I achieved what I wanted ... I guess the concat method would work too:

```
json_obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('object')); //->Creating JSON object from string format

var new_item = {"Vendor":'GUY', "Title": '...', "Year":'...'};

json_obj["Movies"]["Movie"].push(new_item);

JSON.stringify(json_obj) //-> String format
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the `concat` method?

```
var a = {"Movies": { "Movie": [{"Title":"Movie1","Year":"2013"}]}};
var b = {"Movies": { "Movie": [{"Title":"Movie2","Year":"2014"}]}};

var c = {"Movies": { "Movie": a.Movies.Movie.concat(b.Movies.Movie) }};
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Damn. Beat me to it ;) Here's a jsfiddle which looks awfully similar to the answer above http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/ZLHQF/