# How can i combine two json values using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, html

I have two JSON Objects like this:

First one:

```
[{
    "id": 5001,
    "count": "0",
    "type": "None"
},
{
    "id": 5002,
    "count": "0",
    "type": "Glazed"
},
{
    "id": 5005,
    "count": "0",
    "type": "Sugar"
},
{
    "id": 5003,
    "count": "0",
    "type": "Chocolate"
},
{
    "id": 5004,
    "count": "0",
    "type": "Maple"
},
{
    "id": 5009,
    "count": "0",
    "type": "Juice"
}]
```

Second one:

```
[{
    "id": 5001,
    "count": "1"
},
{
    "id": 5002,
    "count": "10"
},
{
    "id": 5005,
    "count": "20"
},
{
    "id": 5003,
    "count": "70"
},
{
    "id": 5004,
    "count": "50"
},
{
    "id": 5009,
    "count": "0"
}]
```

How can I combine these two JSON Objects like:

```
[{
    "id": 5001,
    "count": "1",
    "type": "None"
},
{
    "id": 5002,
    "count": "10",
    "type": "Glazed"
},
{
    "id": 5005,
    "count": "20",
    "type": "Sugar"
},
{
    "id": 5003,
    "count": "70",
    "type": "Chocolate"
},
{
    "id": 5004,
    "count": "50",
    "type": "Maple"
},
{
    "id": 5009,
    "count": "0",
    "type": "Juice"
}]
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since JSON data is an array, you can use the standard array function `.push()`:

```
data.push(data1);
```

#### Fiddle:

```js
var data = [{"id": 1, "name": "Praveen"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Kumar"}];
var newD = [{"id": 3, "name": "StackOverflow"}];
data.push(newD[0]);
```

You can check out the contents of `data`, by using a `console.log(data)`.

---

Or you can also use [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

by passing an empty object as the target(first) argument you can preserve both the objects if however you want to merge the second object you can do it like

```
$.extend(object1, object2);
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/gyysg5zm/

Reference: [Merge two json objects with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478260/merge-two-json-objects-with-jquery).

Comment: JSON data is actually string. It only becomes array when converted

Comment: @charlietfl Yup, the OP can use `JSON.parse()` to convert it. Better right?\

Comment: it's just the definition thing... so many people getting confused these days when they see arrays or objects and calling them JSON and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}
```

from:
[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

and customize for your needs, for example to overwrite lower count.